# Who was stronger, Lucian or William?

Tags: werewolf, underworld

Underworld: Evolution says William became ,"the first and most powerful Lycan."

But Underworld: Rise of the Lycans says Lucian, "possessed a strength and focus that the ones before him did not."

https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Underworld:_Rise_of_the_Lycans

Answer (score 4):

Seeing these two beings were never pitted against each other or ever had a common enemy to rival both it is hard to tell which would be stronger in terms of raw strength or stronger as in a better combatant.

But if you look at them individually it is clear that William was pretty much a beast, he might be the physically strongest of the two but his wild nature doesn't allow him to make full use of his power. Lucian as it is stated possess a greater focus then his for bearers allowing him to utilize strategy.

Take the Thanos VS Hulk fight at the beginning of Infinity war, The Hulk was a savage beast that only knows how to SMASH! But he got easily beaten by Thanos who used precise strikes instead of brute strength.

I assume a fight between William and Lucian would play out the same, with William being the physical stronger one while Lucian wins because he knows where to strike. And that would also make Lucian the greater threat to the Vampires, Because William could be out maneuvered and he had the disadvantage of not being able to utilize armor or weapons like a crossbow. So the vampires had a clear edge, but against Lucian and his followers they had no such advantage and were still physically weaker then the Lycans.

So in short, William was stronger but Lucian was the greater threat.